# adding item to dictionary python with a variable name key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I made a list of lists of possible combinations of n length from a list of items, and now I want to create a dictionary where each key is one of the items from list of lists of possible combinations, so I can start counting how many times each combination occurs in a set of observations (early stages of programming an association rules engine). Here's what I have:

```
import itertools
stuff=(1,2,3,4)
n=1
combs=list()
while n<=len(stuff):
    combs.append(list(itertools.combinations(stuff,n)))
    n = n+1
print combs
viewers={'Jim':(1,3,4), 'Bob':(1,2,4), 'Jerry':(1,4), 'Ben':(2), 'Sal':(1,4)}  
showcount={}
for list in combs:
    for item in list:
        showcount["%s",%(item)]=0
print viewers
print showcount
```

How do I get the item to appear as the key in the dictionary? So for example, I'd like the combination '(1,2,4):0' to be a key value pair so I can later count the number of times '(1,2,4)' appears. I'm pretty new to Python, but I did seach around for an answer and couldn't find one. Apologies if this has been answered and I just couldn't find it.

Comment: what's wrong in storing `(1,2,3)` as value not key.

Comment: This is another one of those questions where you could have answered the question by trying it - tuples are fine as dictionary keys.

Comment: The problem is not using tuples as keys, the problem is how to loop over a list of lists of tuples and get python to make a key in the dictionary for each tuple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use tuples as keys:

```
mydict = { (1, 2, 4): 0 }
```

If you want to count things, take a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects), it makes counting trivial, no need to initialize the keys to 0:

```
counts = collections.Counter()
counts[(1, 2, 4)] += 1
```

Comment: But how do I get python to iterate through the list of lists of tuples and add each tuple as a key in the dictionary? That's the question, sorry if I phrased it poorly. showcount["%s",%(item)]=0 is the problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TomR: No, just `showcount[item] += 1` is enough. There is *no* need for `showcount[item] = 0` because `Counter` auto-magically sets each new key to 0 for you. You can just use `item` as the key, no need to turn it into a string.